# Driving bipolar transistor with mosfet?

Tags: mosfet, bjt, coil, mosfet-driver

Is it a proper way to drive bipolar transistor with mosfet?

Or should I simply skip Q1 and drive coil directly with mosfet? (with extra diode to protect mosfet)

The point is that I have Q1 already on heatsink and connected with thick wires.

This is driver for small tesla coil. Coil inductance value is just for sake of example, it's real value is small/unknown.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcHKir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I also strongly suggest to do a bit more research in how to exite a Tesla coil because 50 V, low inductance and probably low series resistance + little experience is asking for transistors being destroyed !!!

Comment: Well do make the values exact because it does make the difference between not working/working/blowing up.

Comment: @FakeMoustache That's why I'm asking here, as Im trying different driver for Q1. I can easly move coil to collector output.

Comment: Blow up your transistors if you must and don't follow my advice to have a look at how others succesfully did this. Electronics is so simple anyone can do this without any experience/knowing what they're doing :-) :-) :-) OK, it is not that hard but knowledge **is** required, there is no shame in copying what others did. Without experience trying to design your own driver will end in **failure**. Just accept that. Copy someone else's design. Then when you have **more experience** design your own.

Comment: @FakeMoustache thanks for humble comments:) I do electronics ocasionally, so I'm confusing things. Fixed schematics. I'm not trying to re-invent wheel, just adapting what I found on the web.

Answer (score 1):

You should include a diode regardless of whether you use the BJT or MOSFET.

You could drive the coil directly from the MOSFET if it is rated sufficiently for the current, but if you want to leave Q1 as is, I suggest you rearrange it to put the coil at the collector.  I changed the resistor to 47k as I think 68k might be too high, but it will depend on your coil current and transistor gain.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLvLvh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Based on the comments to your original question and the transistor being actually NPN, the above schematic doesn't apply.

Comment: I confused schematics, but I get the idea, thanks.

Comment: Q1 turn off?   .................

Comment: Q1 is a current-controlled device, so if Q2 is off, Q1 would shut off.  But if you feel better about it you can include a pull-up on the base.

Answer (score 1):

Your circuit makes no sense:

[image]

The IRF530 is a power FET that can dissipate 70 W, handle 12 A continuously, and stand off 100 V.  The 2N3906, in contrast, is a small signal transistor that can dissipate around ½ W, handle 200 mA continuously, and stand off 40 V.

I can't even guess why you'd use a beefy power transistor to drive a small signal transistor.

The obvious answer is to drive the coil directly from M1, especially since you already seem to have its gate drive worked out.  That's usually the tricky part with FETs.  Note that the gate drive needs to go from 0 to about 10 V to use the FET effectively.

You also need to make sure that the coil current has a place to go when the transistor switches off.  If you don't give it one, it will make one, probably right thru the transistor trying to be off.  That would be bad for the transistor.

You mentioned something about a Tesla coil.  Those work on resonance, so the current may start flowing thru the effective capacitance in parallel with the coil.  If so, the voltage can reach twice the supply, so you have to make sure the transistor can handle that, or conversely, make the supply low enough.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a proper way to drive bipolar transistor with mosfet?

such things exist - they are called igbt. designed to switch very high currents not suited for mosfets.

in your case, your current levels aren't there yet.